# How to automatically adding z dimension in vertex editor from field attributes

Tags: qgis, vertices

I have geo-coordinates x y and z value, when I created an 3D shapefile, how can I automatically make the z value into Vertex Editors' z dimension??

[image: Z-dimension in vertex editor is not matched]

Comment: Is v.extrude what you want? See: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/254710/how-to-create-a-3d-shapefile-with-qgis-from-values-stored-in-the-attribute-table

Answer (score 2):

**Processing** > **ToolBox** > **GRASS GIS** > **Vector (v.*)** > **v.to.3d**

Use the IPTZ column as the input for "Name of attribute column used for height" parameter.

[image]

Comment: I am able to make all "Z" vertex value through v.to.3d,  Then I used Plugin Point2One, which make it become 2D Shape file with lines again.   So I used v.to.3d again, now this time it made the Z value the same.     My two geo points have different altitude, but v.to.3d reads only one.

Comment: I don't think I understand what you are saying. v.to.3d is only applying one height? Did you choose the field containing a z value or a constant value?