# v.extrude extusion failed - The following layers were not correctly generated

Tags: qgis, grass-gis

I am using QGIS Grass [v.extrude tool](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/254710/how-to-create-a-3d-shapefile-with-qgis-from-values-stored-in-the-attribute-table) for extrusion but it giving me this error (the bold text is error).

```
scale Scale factor sampled raster values default: 1.0 null_value
Height for sampled raster NULL values 
**ERROR: Sorry <TER_8> is not a
valid option** C:\Users\User\Documents>v.out.ogr type="auto"
input="output5c4e838e8af54c7dae5ee537994bc46a"
output="C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\processing_f5800465ab8f4b9b8866d34ee24c0249\d26f9377bcd8450582d55381695f5de2\output.gpkg"
format="GPKG" --overwrite **ERROR: Vector map
<output5c4e838e8af54c7dae5ee537994bc46a> not found**
C:\Users\User\Documents>exit Execution of
<C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\processing_f5800465ab8f4b9b8866d34ee24c0249\grassdata\grass_batch_job.cmd>
finished. Cleaning up default sqlite database ... Cleaning up
temporary files... Press any key to continue . . . Execution completed
in 13.72 seconds Results: {'output':
<QgsProcessingOutputLayerDefinition {'sink':TEMPORARY_OUTPUT,
'createOptions': {'fileEncoding': 'System'}}>}

Loading resulting layers

**The following layers were not correctly generated.<ul><li>C:/Users/User/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_f5800465ab8f4b9b8866d34ee24c0249/d26f9377bcd8450582d55381695f5de2/output.gpkg</li></ul>You
can check the 'Log Messages Panel' in QGIS main window to find more
information about the execution of the algorithm**.
```

Comment: The real error is "ERROR: Sorry <TER_8> is not a valid option" - did you set TER_8 anywhere?

Comment: Ter_8 is a column which i got through the join.

Comment: I have changed its name (column Name) to Heights but now i am getting this error. WARNING: Invalid layer number (-1). Parameter 'height_column', 'cats' or 'where' specified, assuming layer '1'.
ERROR: Column <Heights> does not exist